# Django URL kwargs both in main app and subapp, reverse fails

Tags: django, django-urls

EDIT: Never mind, it was something completely unrelated (wrong URL name).

I have a Django urls.py that includes another urls.py from a subapp. I get "reverse not found" errors when trying to use reverse(). I use keyword arguments in the URL both before and after the include, it's basically:

First urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # Change requests are in a subapp
    url(r'^projects/(?P<project_slug>[^/]+)/changerequests/',
        include('myapp.changerequests.urls')),
)
```

And in the subapp's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^detail/(?P<request_id>\d+)/$',
        views.RequestDetailPage.as_view(),
        name='changerequests_detail'),
)
```

Now I want to find an URL with something like

```
url = reverse('changerequests_detail', kwargs={
               'project_slug': self.project.slug,
               'request_id': str(self.id)})
```

So it uses two kwargs, that are spread out over both urls.pys. But the reverse fails to find an answer (`Reverse for 'changerequests_main' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'project_slug': u'123-2013_monitoring_slibaanwas-hdsr', u'request_id': '2'}' not found.`).

Is that the problem? Is spreading kwargs over urls files this way not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe error occurs because it's trying to reverse `'changerequests_main'` URL, not `'changerequests_detail'`.

Comment: It turns out that I had a different problem first (forgot to add project_slug to reverse) and while trying to find it, I checked with the changerequests_main name. Then I didn't change it back. Thanks for spotting the problem!